# React state the array cannot be updated correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

*Update: here is the [Snack Expo](https://snack.expo.dev/2hpIivBwJ).*

I have a page to show a list. And when I tap on a Delete button, I want to delete the item by id from the list.

The code looks like below:

```
import { useState, memo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const initialData = {
  data: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'A',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'B',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'C',
    },
  ],
};


type Props = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  onClicked: (id: string) => void;
};

const MyView = (props: Props) => {
  const { onClicked, name, id} = props;

  const onPressDelete = useCallback(() => {
    onClicked(id);
  }, [name]);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressDelete}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 28, backgroundColor: 'yellow', marginVertical: 10 }}>{name}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ) ;
}

export default function App() {
  const [pageData, setPageData] = useState(initialData);

  const deleteById = (idToDelete: string) => {
    const currentList = [...pageData.data];
    console.log('current list size == ' + currentList.length);
    const newList = currentList.filter(
      (filteredItem: any) => filteredItem.id !== idToDelete
    );
    console.log('new list size == ' + newList.length);
    setPageData({
      ...pageData,
      data: newList,
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {pageData.data.map((item, index) => (
        <MyView id={item.id} name={item.name} onClicked={deleteById} />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

<s>But the `setPageData` function seems not working properly.</s>

My scenario was like this:

1. I have 3 items in the page at the beginning: A / B / C
2. When I delete C, I saw A and B, this is correct
3. Then I delete B, I saw A, so far so good as well
4. But, when I delete A at last, I saw B and C came out.

For the last iteration, the `current list size == 3` again, I was not able to figure how come the original data was kept, the expected behavior should be there should be 0 items at last.

---

I looked over my code again, it is this part caused the error:

```
const onPressDelete = useCallback(() => {
  onClicked(id);
}, [name]);
```

If I change it to:

```
const onPressDelete = () => {
  onClicked(id);
};
```

then everything will be just fine.

I was wondering how come this affected the result of the list.

Please play it around at [Snack Expo](https://snack.expo.dev/2hpIivBwJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible issue I see with the callback code is that of a possible stale closure over the `pageData` state. Whenever the *next* state depends on the *previous* state you should really use a [functional state update](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) to correctly update from the previous state instead of whatever happens to be closed over in callback scope.

Example:

```js
const deleteById = (idToDelete) => {
  setPageData(pageData => ({
    ...pageData,
    data: pageData.data.filter(
      (filteredItem: any) => filteredItem.id !== idToDelete
    ),
  }));
};
```

There is a logical error in the `MyView` component where the code is memoizing a closure over the passed `onClicked` prop which is `deleteById` in `App`.

```js
// bug version function
const onPressDelete = useCallback(() => {
  onClicked(id);
}, [name]);
```

Per mapped and rendered `MyView` component, the `name` prop never changes, so `onPressDelete` is only ever a reference to the initial `deleteById` callback instance where `pageData.data` is the initial state value with the full array. Each time it's called it's filtering from the initial state value and not what you think is the updated value.

The solution here is to use the correct dependencies, e.g. `id` and `onClicked`:

```js
const onPressDelete = useCallback(() => {
  onClicked(id);
}, [id, onClicked]);
```

Note however that `id` also never changes, it's `onClicked` that changes each render cycle that allows the currently closed over state to be accessed correctly because `deleteById` is a new reference each render in `App`. It's effectively and functionally equivalent to the "good version function" that doesn't attempt to memoize anything at all.

If you need to memoize and provide a stable callback, then you really should memoize `deleteById` in `App`.

Example:

```js
const deleteById = useCallback((idToDelete: string) => {
  const currentList = [...pageData.data];
  const newList = currentList.filter(
    (filteredItem: any) => filteredItem.id !== idToDelete
  );
  setPageData({
    ...pageData,
    data: newList,
  });
}, [pageData]);
```

This still has the external dependency on the `pageData` state to recompute the callback and re-close over the `pageData` state. To eliminate this dependency then use a functional state update and noted initially in this answer.

```js
const deleteById = useCallback((idToDelete: string) => {
  setPageData(pageData => ({
    ...pageData,
    data: pageData.data.filter(
      (filteredItem: any) => filteredItem.id !== idToDelete
    ),
  }));
}, []);
```

### Demo

https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/item-deletion

Comment: Hi @Drew, thanks very much for your answer! I updated the code by following your instruction, and it works perfect! I've read the doc you pointed me to, it makes perfect sense. However may I explain my scenario a little bit more?

Comment: Continue with above:  for my scenario, the interval was about 5 or 10 seconds between each time I delete (call the function deleteById) an item, which is a bit different with the given example in the link (that is to call the same function repeatedly, if the state can't be updated in time, the next call gets the stale data. But I was wondering the cause of mine, I assumed it is enough to finish the update.

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. We can't see where and how `deleteById` is being called to say much more about what may be going on in your code. If this, or any, answer here doesn't sufficiently address your question/issue then please kindly edit your post to include more relevant details and a more complete [mcve] so we can see more of what the code is actually doing overall.

Answer (score 2):

Change your 1st line of `deleteById` function to

```js
const currentList = [...pageData.data];
```

Just edit the state update logic to this in your [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/2hpIivBwJ)

```
setPageData({ ...pageData,  data: [...newList] });
```

This makes a copy of array and doesn't update the existing array.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and the Snacks! But by playing the Snacks, everything looks fine. I will look deeper into my issue. Probably will close this issue for the moment. Thanks again!

Comment: No, this won't change much of anything since `currentList.filter` returns a new array anyway. In other words, it doesn't matter much if it's `currentList.filter` or `pageData.data.filter`, the result is the same, a new array.

Comment: @Kartikey, thanks again for the Snacks. I updated the question and included a minimal reproducible example included. It would be wonderful if by any chance you can help checkout what's the cause of the issue, I appreciate your help so much!

Comment: Hey @LiuWenbin_NO., I've updated the answer check it out.

Comment: hi, thanks for keep looking into it!  it was: `setPageData({...pageData, data: newList, });`, I changed it to yours `setPageData({ ...pageData,  data: [...newList] });`, seems the same issue is still there. I saved it as this: https://snack.expo.dev/3q7mjFVw_

Answer (score 1):

###### update state array

example code in expo [example](https://snack.expo.dev/LGrI1uP9M)

App.js

```
const initList:IList[] = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name:"One"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name:"Two"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name:"Three"
  },
]

interface IList {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
export default function App() {

  const [list, setList] = useState<IList[]>(initList)
  // example
  const [anotherData, setAnotherData] = useState(initAnother); 


  const handleDelete = useCallback((id: string) => {
    const filteredData = list.filter((a)=> a.id !== id);
    setList(filteredData);
  },[list]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>    
      <View>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(list)}</Text>
        {
          list.map((item)=>(
            <MyItem item={item} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
            
          ))
        }
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

MyItem

```
interface IMyItemProps {
  item: IList,
  handleDelete: (id: string) => void;
}

const MyItem = ({item, handleDelete}: IMyItemProps) => {
  const { id, name } = item;
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity key={id} onPress={()=> handleDelete(id)}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 28, backgroundColor: 'yellow', marginVertical: 10 }}>{name}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helps sir! I updated the question and included the minimal reproducible example, if ever possible please help check it out, I will be much appreciate for the helps!

Comment: Hi, I know your problem `const newList = pageData.filter((filteredItem: IPageData) => filteredItem.id !== id);` change another param value instead of filteredItem. when I change like `const newList = pageData.filter((b: IPageData) => b.id !== id);` it is working well. that is very wiered problem. [here is your original code example](https://snack.expo.dev/DdSq8wcC3). I updated it a little bit

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helps! Yewin! I read your updates, and your updated version works well for me too. However I still think the root cause was in the bug version of const onPressDelete, please check it out at here: https://snack.expo.dev/dDf6PxART

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer Yewin! TBH, I was wondering for the reason for why this `const onPressDelete = useCallback` will affect the result. Thank you again for helps!